# Modificar un archivo binario en C

Tags: c, archivo

necesito leer y modificar un archivo binario, estoy usando este codigo:

```
FILE *fp; t_data dat; fp=fopen("file.bin","r+b"); 
fread(&dat,sizeof(t_data),1,fp); 
while(!feof(fp))
{
    if(dat.aaaa==2018)
    {
        int pos = ftell(fp)-sizeof(t_data);
        dat.prec=2;
        fseek(fp,pos,SEEK_SET);
        fwrite(&dat,sizeof(t_data),1,fp);
    }
    fread(&dat, sizeof(t_data),1,fp);
}
fclose(fp);
```

el programa entra en un loop aparte de que no se modifican los datos con los que quiero trabajar, no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal, que puede ser?
gracias

Answer (score 0):

ok, encontre el motivo de porque se hacia el loop

```
FILE *fp; t_data dat; fp=fopen("file.bin","r+b"); 
fread(&dat,sizeof(t_data),1,fp); 
while(!feof(fp))
{
    if(dat.aaaa==2018)
    {
        int pos = ftell(fp)-sizeof(t_data);
        dat.prec=2;
        fseek(fp,pos,SEEK_SET);
        fwrite(&dat,sizeof(t_data),1,fp); // faltaba esta linea
    }
    fread(&dat, sizeof(t_data),1,fp);
}
fclose(fp);
```

hay que llamar a fseek o rewind entre escritura y lectura para resetear el estado de lectura/escritura antes de cambiar de nuevo a modo lectura